# Powershell (pwsh) user bug?

Tags: fedora, gnome-terminal, bugs, powershell

I'm on Fedora 33 + Gnome.
Open `gnome-terminal` in a folder (let's say, the Downloads), open another terminal tab/window and type `pwsh`: if you check the value of `$profile` it refers to a temporary location.

How can this be fixed?

It seems a bug: if I type `gnome-terminal --tab` everything is ok.

After having investigated further, it IS a bug that happens when you click on *"Open in terminal"* from Nautilus: even if you don't use Powershell, but just the standard `gnome-terminal` configuration as-is, you can see that if you open a new terminal from an already running one (opened from Nautilus) you won't be able to access X, for example (eg: try to open `gedit`...)